# Unable to FindOneAndUpdate UserModel with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently building out the backend of my application using Express and Mongoose. I'd like to be able to update an existing user with new details.

Currently my flow is a user uses the `/signup` endpoint with an email/password. Then they use the `/login` endpoint to get a token.

I'm able to successfully get the user with a `GET` to the `/profile` endpoint, but I'd like to be able to `POST` to the `/profile` endpoint with a JSON object, and have those values added to the user model. Here is my function.

I've looked at the mongoose docs and on here, and nothing seems to work for me.

I know I'm getting back the correct user, but it's not even being updated. Even when I check the DB it's not updated.

And the catch isn't catching any errors.

```
router.post('/profile', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { _id } = req.user;
  const { firstName, lastName, role } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: _id },
      {
        $set: {
          firstName,
          lastName,
          role,
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating user:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }

  res.send({});
});
```

Comment: instead of the `$set` if u just have the update objetc `.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: _id }, { firstName, lastName, role, } )` what happens

Comment: @cmgchess I tried that and have the same result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it. I'll blame the fact I'm new to this and it was late.

But I didn't have the new fields on the UserModel, so mongoose didn't know what to with the new data.

As soon as I added the fields in to the UserModel, my code worked first time.

Thanks for everyones help though, it did help with the debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Using `findByIdAndUpdate` would be better because of the need to find it by the document's `ObjectId`. Also, need to add `{new: true}` for returning the modified document:

```js
router.post('/profile', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { _id } = req.user;
  const { firstName, lastName, role } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      _id,
      {
          firstName,
          lastName,
          role
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    console.log(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating user:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }

  res.send({});
});
```

As another option, you can use `then-catch` instead of `try-catch` to make the code simpler and clearer:

```js
return await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      _id,
      {
          firstName,
          lastName,
          role
      },
      { new: true }
    )
    .then(user => {
         console.log(user);
         return res.send({});
    })
    .catch(error => {
         console.error('Error updating user:', error);
         return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    });
```

Also, **if the `req.body` only includes update fields**, then you can use it as a short way: 
 (However, creating an update model by taking properties from the request would be clearer!)

```js
const updatedUserModel = req.body;
await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, updatedUserModel, { new: true });
```

Here is the documentation link: [Mongoose - findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndUpdate())

Hope, it's clear and helpful

Comment: That doesn't work either I'm afraid. The user object still isn't being updated.

Comment: @Kpizzle I saw your answer. So, my answer still can be helpful for you. I tried to explain better practices for updating documents and how to write them cleaner/simpler. So, I hope, it's useful.

Comment: This is a good answer. If OP hadn't forgot to add properties to schema then this would have been the correct solution. Although I wouldn't put the whole `req.body` in the update document. Doing that would allow users to set values you don't want them to such as `admin : true` or `discount: 99%` etc. Always just take the properties you expect from `req.body`.

Comment: @jQueeny Thank you for the comment, you are right, I wouldn't use the `req.body` for updating either. I just wanted to mention that if the `req.body` **only includes the update fields**, then it can be used as a short/another way but yeah, creating an update model would be clearer as you specified. I just updated the answer by adding a short explanation for it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **`new:true`** in the fincOneAndUpdate object.

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same result. The original object is logged, without any updates.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).